# Can I use Jenkins Artifactory Plugin (DSL) to invoke the Artifactory REST API?

Tags: rest, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, dsl

I can't find the complete Artifactory DSL documentation. There are examples of how to do some things with DSL on the "Working With Pipelines Jobs on Jenkins", but how do we know what else is available besides `upload()`, `download()`, `newBuildInfo()`, etc.?  The best I have found is by studying the jenkins-artifactory-plugin source code on github.

Second, since I haven't found it yet, is there any way to invoke the Artifactory REST API from the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin (DSL)?

Answer (score 1):

All of the Artifactory Pipeline APIs are available in this page:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins
This page also includes a link to a few examples in github.
Using other APIs, which are not documented, is not recommend, because they are not meant to be accessed externally, and therefore may change in future releases.
Currently there's no generic REST call API documented. To invoke a REST call from a pipeline script you can use an external REST client, such as cUrl, from pipeline's "sh" step.